# Why is the jquery on my site malfunctioning?

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my site...
http://matiny.tk/

The two characters (#excalibur & #black) on the side, as well as the logo (#logo) have all been selected with

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var theNumber = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('#excalibur').css({
        'transform': 'translateY(' + theNumber / 2 + 'px)'
    });
    $('#black').css({
        'transform': 'translateY(' + theNumber / 2 + 'px)'
    });
    $('#logo').css({
        'transform': 'translateY(' + theNumber/1.5 + 'px)'
    });
});
```

I've already tested the code numerous times. After I uploaded it to my site, the code stopped working both locally and remotely. The scrolling function stopped working only with the characters, but NOT with the logo... even though it's copy-pasted.

Comment: What exactly is the functionality you are trying to achieve?

Comment: The same parallax scrolling effect you see with the logo, but a bit faster on the characters (hence the larger denominator in the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your entire `$(window).scroll()` call inside of your `$(document).ready()` function.

Comment: Thanks. Though I'm not sure what in the world happened.

Comment: @Matiny What happened is, your images loaded much faster when running the site locally, so it didn't matter that you weren't waiting for the page to fully load before setting up your scroll listener.  On your hosted site, the images take (usually imperceptibly) longer to load, so they didn't exist in the DOM yet when you tried to set up the listener.